# Is there a way to rename "range" "majorDimension" "values" in script for cleaner data via api output?

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is my HTTP data api output in GS, but I think need to work on either the structure in GS or my url api address. In the GS I have row #1 "name" "age" "city". Or should I look for a group function for cell A1, B1, and C1 so my api output looks cleaner?

```html
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:HV7745",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "name",
      "age",
      "city"
    ],
    [
      "Rex",
      "55",
      "woon"
    ],
    [
      "Bec",
      "34",
      "paw"
    ],
    [
      "Tim",
      "37",
      "prov"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: The output is clean. Why do you think it's not clean?

Comment: I would like to group like this..

https://api.covid19api.com/summary

Comment: Unfortunately, Sheets API cannot directly return the values as such JSON object. So in this case, it is required to achieve your goal using a script. How about this?